# Compare two columns, but only first 4 letters - vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns - Column A and Column B, filled with different items. Column B is always shorter (it has less items than column A). I need a VBA formula in Excel 2007 to do the following:

1) Compare first 4 letters of items in column B to first 4 letters of items column A

2) Find a match in column A and copy the whole content of the cell in column A to Column C, next to the item in column B that matched.

Here's what I've made so far:

```
    Sub Compare()
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim x As Long
xTitleId = "Compare"
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Range1 :", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Range2:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng1 In Range1
    xValue = Rng1.Value

    For Each Rng2 In Range2
    x = Rng2.Row
        If xValue = Rng2.Value Then
            Rng1.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & x).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code does the job, but it compares whole words and I need just first 4 letters. I know of the function Left, but I don't know how to implement it here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `xValue = Left(Rng1.Value, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

The function that you need is the following:

```
test = Left("YOURVALUE",4)
```

Of course there is also the opposite function:

```
test = Right("YOURVALUE",5)
```

In firts case the result in test is "YOUR" and in second case is "VALUE"

To copy value in colum C you can use two strategy:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & x).Cells(row_index, column_index)
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & x).PasteSpecial
```